# Knockout binding not updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My knockout binding is not updating. I have a field that I have set as

```
this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
```

When I call:

```
AppViewModel.firstName(name);
```

I need it to update. Here is a jsfiddle:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
}
// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

// When I click button I want the name to change
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    var name = 'New Name';
    AppViewModel.firstName(name);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d577K/38/

Comment: are you sure thats the right fiddle?  Doesn't seem to have any of your code in it...

Comment: also can we see your html markup?

Comment: Just updated it. The HTML is there sorry..

Comment: yeah I figured it out, you were just using an older version of the fiddle. no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing the AppViewModel class instead of the actual object... try instantiating the view model before binding with knockout, then reference the instance:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
}
var vm = new AppViewModel();
// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(vm);

//When I click button I want the name to change
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
var name = 'New Name';
vm.firstName(name);

});
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/d577K/178/

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
new AppViewModel()
```

you're creating a new AppViewModel object.  However you never save a reference to that object.

when you try to update `AppViewModel.firstName(name);`, `AppViewModel` is your constructor function and you're calling a method that doesn't exist on the constructor function.  You need to create your object as a variable and then reference it.

```
var app = new AppViewModel();

...

app.firstName(name);
```

Here's an update to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d577K/39/), its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to keep the name update function outside of the model?

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/dvdrom000/d577K/41/

**html update**

```
<input type="button" value="test" data-bind="click: NewName" />
```

**js**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

    this.NewName = function(){
        this.lastName("New name");
    }
}
// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```